# Can I set range (min/max) for a column when creating PostgreSQL table

Tags: java, postgresql, types, database-migration, flyway

I use the following table creation script in Flyway and wondering if it is possible to define a range or min/max value for a column.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room (
    // ...
    temperature   NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    room_no       VARCHAR(40)
    );
```

So, can I set a min/max or range (5 to 30) for `temperature` field?

Comment: you can do that with triggers. `on insert` you will have values you just insert and is they do not match your criteria(bigger than) you can either throw an error OR set the most possible min or max value.

Comment: @msangel: no trigger required. A check constraint will do

Answer (score 2):

Use a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room (
    temperature   NUMERIC NOT NULL check (temperature between 5 and 30),
    room_no       VARCHAR(40)
    );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I use Hibernate and check the value using annotation before persisting to database? Do I still need to add this constraint on PsotgreSQL migration script?